# Can't access hazelcast mancenter using kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast

I'm trying to investigate and learn a little more about kubernetes and I followed the guide https://blog.hazelcast.com/deploy-monitor/ to install the hazelcast monitor in my kubernetes cluster.

If I see the kubernetes dashboard it has the 2 deployments, 3 pods and my-service as green.

Running this:

```
λ kubectl get service my-service
NAME         TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
my-service   NodePort   10.104.54.32   <none>        8080:30476/TCP   2h
```

But when I run

```
λ minikube service my-service
Opening kubernetes service default/my-service in default browser...
```

And It opens the browser and if I access:

```
http://192.168.99.100:30476/mancenter
```

I get a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Hazelcast Management Center are you using? Recent versions of Management Center use `/hazelcast-mancenter` as the default URL.

Answer (score 0):

As @emre said, the url was wrong. The guide I followed is outdated.

Should be

```
http://192.168.99.100:30476/hazelcast-mancenter/
```